# It's so word-nerdy it hurts?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was randomly reading few questions in english stackexchange and i found this question

[How do you quote a passage that has used '[sic]' mistakenly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/how-do-you-quote-a-passage-that-has-used-sic-mistakenly)

look at the first comment by e.James

what does "It's so word-nerdy it hurts" mean?

Comment: "It's clever, authoritative, awesome – I hate it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thank you for linking to that question! I thoroughly enjoyed reading it, the comments and the answers.

Now, as for "nerdy", derived from "nerd", it's used to describe an activity that seems complex, uninteresting and at least on the surface useless to most people. Kids that programmed computers were once described as such, since it was complicated, it was of little interest to "normal" people and most people didn't see any direct benefits in it being done.

Although "nerd" has started to take on a more positive meaning (no doubt due to the fact that some famous "nerds" showed that not only was their strange hobby useful to others, it also could turn into a financially very interesting career), "nerdy" still seems to have mostly negative connotations as in "overdoing it", "looking too much at details" or "spending time and effort on something uninteresting".

`Word-nerdy` now would imply that this nerdy behavior is applied to words, which seems indeed that case in the linked question. It asks a very, very detailed question about a way to correct a former correction that was actually not a correction.

`so ... that it hurts` is an idiomatic expression to indicate that whatever is so ..., is *so* much so, that it could cause physical pain, even if there is no physical action involved.

"I laughed so hard that it hurts" is more literal: laughing can make you hurt. But the phrase is also used in situations like "I miss you so much that it hurts", meaning that the psychological impact of missing someone is so big it is comparable to experiencing physical pain.

In general "so ... that it hurts" is just a figurative way of overstating how much ... was true - it is stronger than just saying that something was very ....

(If this seems a long and complex answer: I was writing this before the question got migrated :P )